# I'm having some issues using Html value

Tags: php, html

I've a column inside my table to put Html codes, I will use this table for email templating.
I have inside my page, all the templates inside my table, with two buttons, one to remove, and another one to edit.
The edit button shows the code inside a textbox, and to do the preview I did an echo to the code column.

```
    <div class="tempcolumn">
    <div><textarea name="ai" rows="15" cols="100" name="code" placeholder="Code">
       <?php echo $get_temp; ?></textarea></div>
    </div>        
    Preview
    <div class="tempcolumn">
    <p><?php echo $get_temp; ?></p>
    <div></div>
    </div>
```

To recognize the code and the id i created an hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="temp_id" value="'.$val['template_id'].'">
<input type="hidden" name="temp_code" value="'.$val['text'].'">
```

The script is working, but when i insert inside the code column some `"<"` or `"="` doesn't work

Is inferfering because it reads the input value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="temp_id" value=" Value here + 'random character that closes the tag'  ">
```

Is there a easier way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: you have to use " &lt; " instead of < (less than)
and " &#61; " instead of = (equal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try;

```
htmlspecialchars($value)
```

This will convert html characters to their non-interfering cousins.

See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php as I can't post the equivalents without them becoming characters.

Comment: Do i use it like this? <input type="hidden" name="temp_code" value="'.htmlspecialchars($val['text']).'">